# How to shorten this formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I create conditional formatting. So it will check multiple cells to see if at least one of them is not blank, then it will return `TRUE`. If all those cells are blank then it will return `FALSE`.

The code is used is working perfectly, the problem is it's too long:

```
=(not(isblank(M6))+ not(isblank(P6))+  not(isblank(S6)) +not(isblank(V6)) + not(isblank(Z6)) +not(isblank(AC6)) + not(isblank(AF6))+ not(isblank(AI6))+not(isblank(AL6))+not(isblank(AO6))+ not(isblank(AR6))   )=1
```

The cells to be checked is skipped every 2nd column. How to shorten this formula?

Comment: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbgcH.png**

Answer (score 0):

shorter syntax would be:

```
=(M6<>"")+(P6<>"")+(S6<>"")+(V6<>"")+(Z6<>"")+
 (AC6<>"")+(AF6<>"")+(AI6<>"")+(AL6<>"")+(AO6<>"")+(AR6<>"")=1
```